# Testing code where you don't know the output in advance

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

My current project is rather complicated and does a lot of math, of which I don't know the results in advance. I am trying to write unit tests (in JUint); I currently have some tests I've already written, and then I look at the results by hand to see if they "seem" correct, but since my program is how I'm determining the results of the complicated math, I'm not really sure how I verify accuracy.

I have other unit tests for testing very small pieces of the code, but I'm not sure how to write a test for larger chunks of it. Anyone have any thoughts and guidelines?

A little more info, it's not one number. It's more like: "input: 100,000 lines of csv data" output "100,000 of csv analysis". But the lines depend on each other, running the code on 10 lines of csv data isn't enough to do the math meaningfully.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what a correct range might be?

Comment: @JasonSperske I added another sentence to try to answer that question

Comment: To whoever close voted this question, it is a real question to which there are several real answers. Just because there's no code doesn't mean it's not real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing math requires that you be a mathematician, even if you're a really bad one. There's no way around it. With that in mind, here are some methods that mathematicians use to check their answers:

- **Derive the input from the answer**, forcing you to think backwards.
- **Use a different method** to get to the same answer.
- **Break the problem down** into smaller, more easily verified steps.
- **Try using the results** in the real world, and observe whether bad things happen.

If you know approximately what answer your program should output, then you could check to see if your program gives close to the right answer, and then hope it is correct and use it for your unit tests. But in my experience (game development), real, hardcore math is the most reliable way to check yourself. Plus you have one of the world's most advanced calculators at your fingertips. :)

P.S. Don't forget to leave some variance in your unit tests. Especially when doing more advanced math, there are multiple correct ways of doing it that give slightly different answers due to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: I'm not a really bad mathematician; I actually think the program works correctly right now. I just want to have a unit test so I can be sure... :p

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to say is that math requires knowledge and discipline to ensure that you get the right answer. And I suppose it also helps to check your answer using more math... I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I'm not using floating point arithmetic, I'm using `BigDecimal` and `divide(..., MathContext.DECIMAL64)`

Comment: I just had a look at the BigDecimal docs, and yes, it is an enormous float, pure and simple. Unless you have a good reason to round a particular way, you need to use a bit of variance to prevent round-off differences from failing your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pick specific inputs and have an expected result for those inputs.  If you cant do a few test case results by hand, you should break down the pieces you are testing into multiple testable pieces.  You could also solve the math problem using a different technique in the tests then in the item under test.  The problem with this is that if they differ, which one is wrong .. but at least you know what to look for.

Comment: It's less that the math is difficult and more that there's a lot of it. It's actually very simple calculations... but lots of iterations and input data required

Comment: @durron597  Then I would just find a few significant data points and grind out the answer for each.  Maybe on a spreadsheet.  Sorry no magic answer

Answer (score 0):

This is largely dependent on the type of math you're doing.  For example, if you were solving differential equations then you would verify that you got the same answer with half the step size, or you would compare your results to a known accurate (but slow) method like the inverse euler method.

Without knowing what type of math you're doing, I'm assuming that you're using double precision arithmetic.  Try comparing your results to an arbitrary precision library like BigDecimal to verify that you're not running into a lot of roundoff and truncation error.

Comment: Everything I'm doing is in BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestions are might a bit trivial:

- Try to provide input for which the output can be expected (all zero data, all zero data except one value, etc)
- If possible try to write code for parts of the checks you do manually and run on large/many input
- Implement again the code using different algorithms (or by different developer) and cross check the two implementations
- For small scale, manually checked runs see code coverage (for example with Jacoco http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) and try to modify input/create new inputs to increase code coverage